# .NET GDI+ drawing performance

Tags: .net, drawing, gdi

I need to draw about 1000 lines. Those lines change about 25 times per second (so, 25000 lines per second). What can i use to have an acceptable performance while doing so? I prefer not to use directX calls, since this software will also need to run on servers, which don't have directX by default.

Two different ways i tried to do this, but gave me a melting cpu:

Setup1 - standard .NET calls:

- double buffered panel
- drawing on memory bitmap (clearing and redrawing lines with Graphics.DrawLine)
- copying the bitmap to the panel with Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled
- profiler says those two graphics calls are bottleneck

Setup2 - dllimport calls of gdi:

- double buffered panel
- drawing on memory bitmap with MoveToEx and LineTo from gdi
- copying the bitmap to the panel with BitBlt
- profiler says those unmanaged calls are bottleneck

Would performance increase if I use WPF instead of Winforms? Or is the only way to do this, by using directX or third party library?

Cheers

Comment: What size are the lines?

Comment: They have variable lengths, ranging somewhere between 1 and 500 pixels.

Comment: Is the number of lines fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The calling overhead may be the limiting factor.  In vanilla GDI, there is a [PolyPolyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that lets you draw many lines in a single call.  If all your lines are connected, then there's a simpler [Polyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as well.  I assume there are GDI+ equivalents for those.  I'd profile with those.  Even if it takes some work to bundle up your coordinates into the array(s) required by these functions, it's likely to be faster than ~1000 calls to the individual line drawing functions.

Comment: I think that [Graphics.DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx) is the equivalent.  There are also other batching style drawing calls: [Graphics.DrawBieziers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds101091.aspx), [Graphics.DrawRectanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfth7x55.aspx), [Graphics.FillRectanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c3h7524.aspx).

Comment: @BasiK: With PolyPolyline, you can draw many disconnected lines.

Comment: Thanks for the info. While timings seem slightly better with the PolyPolyline call, user experience has no noticible difference.

Comment: @BasiK: Can you give some more concrete timing information?  Are you sure that the bottleneck is the line drawing?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a fixed number of lines:

Use WPF and add the lines once to a canvas.

Every tick, update the ends of the lines as needed. You can change other properties as well.

I'd try this because it is the easiest way to get close to DirectX without using it directly.

In any case: having this many graphical operations on a server without decent hardware will always be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The only advice I can give is that you seem to have direct access to hardware so use a standard double buffering method. Maybe combined with multi-threading if your hardware would support it or just a memory queue like a collection of bitmaps ready to be drawn, remember the processor can do thousands of in memory operations in the time it takes to make one IO operation (screen draw). You could literally have a process that takes data and does the transformation to a in memory surface (a bitmap if you want ) and keeps adding them in sequence, to generics collection, after a certain "buffer size" (collection size) has been reached lets say for the next 5 minutes of images it can be coded to wait until more of the collection has been consumed by the process with the panel. Then in the panel OnPaint equivalent it takes a memory surface from the bottom of the stack and swaps out the present one with one from the bottom of the collection. You could give the thread with the drawing task more processing priority because the other thread will naturally be faster. Remember to lock the collection of memory surfaces with the different threads so that it's thread safe. Good Luck.